# Three.js rendering object without adding to scene?

Tags: performance, data-structures, three.js, voxel

I'm creating a game in three.js. It has a lot of objects, and I'm using hashtables and chunk data structures to increase performance.
However, every object (simple cubes/planes) is added to the scene by Scene.add(geometry);

So, three.js stores the objects in a datastructure which could be not the best structure.

My questions are:
Does it matter how three.js stores the added objects?
And is there a way to render objects in the render loop manually, without having to add it to the scene by using Scene.add(...); ?

How do other games, like voxel.js, solve this problem? It looks like voxel.js has a great performance compared to my game. And actually, a voxel game exists just of simple planes. My game is almost the same as a minecraft-like block world, where all blocks exist of planes. Only the visible planes are added to the scene. But I don't get the same good performance as a voxel.js game. I want to figure out what I can do to make it faster.

Comment: They merge all the planes into one geometry and draw them in one go. It is very inefficient for the gpu to draw one plane at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So is there a way to improve the speed of my game? As I now know, three.js creates one big geometry, but I still have to store all seperate geometries to have a reference to them. And as far as I could figure out, voxel also does. But my game still has low performance, and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the geometry storage I do by my own.

Comment: I dont think three.js does geometry merging for you automatically. Cant comment on your own geometry storage without any information on what it is.

Comment: I've got functions for creating blocks. All blocks exists of planes, because sides (planes) which are not needed are not created. Now I store all blocks in a multidenensional array as:               `blocks[x][y][z] = {'planes': [/* plane geometries */]};`. All blocks I create, are also added to the scene by _scene.add();_  Maybe I could better change a lot, and just create one big geometry for each chunk. The sides of the blocks are not planes then, but just vertices I add to the chunk geometry?